# Why can I access iPhone's location without "import CoreLocation"?

Tags: swift, mapkit, core-location

I am able to access a device's location with the following code. I am using MapKit instead of CoreLocation. I thought this instance `CLLocationManager()` and method `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` were only available through the CoreLocation framework?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        locationManager.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        for currentlocation in locations{
            print("\(index): \(currentlocation)")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapKit imports CoreLocation so you don't need to. Just like you don't need to import Foundation because you get that from UIKit.